# socket.io polling 404 error

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I try to learn socket.io on my web server. I have installed node.js and socket.io on my server. I have prepared web site my socket javascript code is work properly -listening port 3000 on console- but when i try to run example chat application, i got "socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423949334574-31 404 (Not Found)" error. Where is mistake?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
io.emit('chat message', msg);
 });
 });

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

There is my index.html script:

```
<script>
  var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#messagebox').val());
    var mesaj = $('#messagebox').val();
    $('.messageBoard').prepend('<p style="display: none">'+mesaj+'</p>');
    $('#messagebox').val('');
    $('.messageBoard').find('p:first-child').show('slideDown');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('.messageBoard').prepend('<p style="display: none">'+mesaj+'</p>');
  });
</script>
```